# Error: ErrImagePull : failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden while creating kubernetes deployment on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, oauth, authorization

### Case

I am following tutorial: [Deploy a Spring Boot Java app to Kubernetes on Google Kubernetes Engine](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-springboot-kubernetes?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Flearn%2Fpathways%2Fjava-cloud-fundamentals%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fcodelabs.developers.google.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fcloud-springboot-kubernetes#4) . I came to the step when I want to deploy my application (docker image of it) to kubernetes. But after I create the deployment  the pods are not starting because there is problem with pulling the image (Error: ErrImagePull).

I create the deployment like that:

```
 kubectl create deployment questy-java --image=us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1
```

After running the command:

```
kubectl describe pod questy-java-54dbd6ccd4-5cb94
```

I am getting event information:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  36s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/questy-java-54dbd6ccd4-tmdkl to gke-questy-java-cluster-default-pool-ca7ad417-lxkw
  Normal   Pulling    23s (x2 over 35s)  kubelet            Pulling image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1"
  Warning  Failed     23s (x2 over 35s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1": failed to resolve reference "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1": failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
  Warning  Failed     23s (x2 over 35s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    8s (x2 over 35s)   kubelet            Back-off pulling image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1"
  Warning  Failed     8s (x2 over 35s)   kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

The root couse seems to be mentioned in here:

> failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status:
> 403 Forbidden

Anyhow the tutorial did not mention any additional steps to mantain authentication or authorisation.

### What I have tried:

1. I have checked the VPC networks dashboard to see if Private Google Access is enabled and it looks fine:

[image]

2. I have followed instructions to install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin from: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke. Recreating the deployment after this change did not help.
3. Created new repository in the Artifact Registry and tried to deploy my image there
4. build  an entirely new Docker container and tried to deploy it in new repository
5. Tried to deploy questy-java image directly from Google Cloud Console:
   [image]

---

6. Run the command:

```
    gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.dev
```

7. Checked the path throughly. I have copied and paste the path to the image directly from Console:
   [image]
   I have also tried to run the commands:

```
    docker pull \
        us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1
```

It was successfull.

### Question

What could be the reason of this error? What is the most elegant way to fix the issue?

### Edit

I have checked the path to the image directly from Console and it is

```
  us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/quizdev/codelabrepo/questy-java:v1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Error: ErrImagePull : failed to fetch oauth token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden** is due to authorization issue where the Artifact registry is not having the necessary permissions to pull the image.

Refer to this [Troubleshooting error 4xx issues](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#troubleshooting_error_400_issues) Authentication and authorization errors when connecting to GKE clusters.  Set the environment variables to print the access token and Verify that your access token is valid by following the steps mentioned in the  Troubleshooting error 4xx issues.

Also as per this [Troubleshoot doc](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/troubleshoot) you can check the following:

- Verify that the full path of the image that you are pushing is
  correct. The path must include the registry hostname, Google Cloud
  project ID, repository, and image. For example:
  us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-rep
- Verify that the account that is pulling the image has necessary
  permissions to read from the repository. you must grant the [Artifact
  Registry Reader role](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#roles) to the runtime service account then only
  this will help to pull the image.
- If you are using Docker or another third-party tool, you must:
  [Grant permissions](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#grant) to the account that interacts with the
  repository.
- Refer to the [ImagePullBackOff and ErrImagePull](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#ImagePullBackOff) which indicate
  that the image used by a container cannot be loaded from the image
  registry.

Comment: how to check point nr 2 and nr 3 ? Which is the account that is pulling the image? And yes the image is docker, yet the same question which is the docker account that interacts with the repository?

Comment: Find this [doc for point nr 2](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control) and [doc for point nr 3](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication)

Comment: I do not see there this information.

Comment: Google Kubernetes Engine can pull images directly from Docker repositories. Some versions include pre-configured support for pulling images from Artifact Registry Docker repositories. Refer to this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/integrate-gke#permissions) in pulling the image.  refer  to finding the [Artifact registry service account](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/ar-service-account).

Comment: After running `gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev` it's `Error response from daemon: Head "https://europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/.../manifests/latest": unauthorized: authentication failed`. The reader role is in place for the VM, pull command I've copy-pasted from the Google web-ui, what else does it want?

Comment: Alright, there is another thing: access scopes of the VMs. Must have the "storage-ro" access scope.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether the default service account is 'overwritten' by the node pool service account? The documentation mentions to enable the default service account, right? That didn't work for our GKE nodes though. We had to use the node pool service account.

Comment: @HemanthKumar it's extremely hard to find out what is "the account that is pulling the image". Presumably it's set per nodepool, but `gcloud describe` shows only "default", which is obviously invalid service account email. Web UI console doesn't even show what service account it's using, nor oauth scopes on any page.

Answer (score 5):

I have followed the tips from @Hemanth Kumar and finaly what solved my problem was adding a Artifact Registry Reader role for specific repository to the service account user which runs in GKE.

I did it via Google Cloud Console:
[image]